# hyperlink to a sheet in excel

Tags: excel

is it possible to create a hyperlink in an excel document , clicking on which opens a particular sheet in the excel document . please let me know ?

Comment: Sub Macro1()
' Macro recorded 10/06/2008 by Me
    Range("B4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        "C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\My Book.xls", SubAddress:= _
        "Sheet1!A1", TextToDisplay:="MyLink"
End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add that hyperlink in the same workbook then

a. **Right click** on cell in which you want to display hyperlink and click **"Hyperlink"**

b. It presents you a dialog. From left pane titled **"Link to"**, press **"Place in this document"**

c. Your worksheet names will appear in the list box titled **"Select a place in this document"**

d. Select the desired sheet and write the text you want to display and click "OK".

Answer (score 0):

If it's a hyperlink on your website, and you can choose what worksheet you want to use, simply open that particular sheet, save, then close Excel. It will open the workbook on whichever sheet it was closed on.